# A client error (MalformedCertificate) to parse certificate.

Tags: ssl, certificate

So I have been working on this for hours now and no luck.  I have configured OpenSSL, created private a private key, created a csr, submitted the csr to a certificate authority, received the approved certificate and now when I try to upload it I have no luck. I am using this format:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name certificate_object_name --certificate-    body file://public_key_certificate_file --private-key file://privatekey.pem
```

When I try to upload it with file:// I get the following:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name steptproductions --certificate-body file://Users/markhoyt/Downloads/www_steptproductions_com/www_steptproductions_com.crt.pem  --private-key file://Users/markhoyt/private-key.pem


Error parsing parameter '--certificate-body': file does not exist: Users/markhoyt/Downloads/www_steptproductions_com/www_steptproductions_com.crt.pem
```

When I try to upload it with file:/ I get the following:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name car.pem --certificate-body file:/Users/markhoyt/Downloads/www_steptproductions_com/www_steptproductions_com.crt.pem  --private-key file:/Users/markhoyt/private-key.pem

A client error (MalformedCertificate) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format.
```

I have created an instance and am logged onto Amazon Linux AMI with:

```
ssh -i steptproductions.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-183-166-45.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I cannot seem to get the files to upload to the server.  Can anyone help?

Comment: did you create your private key with a password (or passphrase)?

Comment: @user261490 does it make a difference? I have the same error for a key wirhout password